# What are the solutions of $x^n+a^n=0$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

For what values $a$, the equation $x^n+a^n=0$ has $n$ different solutions? what are the solutions?
(the question refers to complex solutions).

Comment: If your equation were $x^n=a^n$ then the solutions would be $x=a\zeta_n^k$ for $0 \le k < n$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. These are all distinct, save for when $a=0$. How might you modify this argument for your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), since for every value of $n>0$ this is a polynomial of degree $n>0$ there are exactly $n$ roots (counting multiplicy), in particular there is always $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $z^n+a^n=0$.

In order to get all solutions you can use [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Edit: For $a=0$ we have $x^n=0$ hence $x=0$ is the only solution, for $a\neq 0$ there are $n$ *different* solutions.

Comment: i meant, different solutions..

Comment: @TomerGalanti - all the solutions are indeed different in your case, see Clive comment

Comment: Provided $a \neq 0$, all $n$ solutions are different.  If $a=0$ then the only solution is $x=0$.

Comment: @DavidWallace - thank you, I edited